# Matrix and its inverse have the same singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values

What is known about matrices which have the same singular values as their inverses? Note that this is equivalent to saying that if $A$ satisfies this condition and $\sigma$ is a singular value of $A$, then $1/\sigma$ is also a singular value of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

The singular values of an invertible (real) matrix $A$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^T A$ (which are the same as those of $A A^T$). If $B = A^T A$,  you're saying that $B$ and $B^{-1}$ have the same eigenvalues.